# Conflicting types for a function

Tags: function

I tried to compile this but I keep getting a conflicting type error. Im not really sure what to do or how to fix i![enter image description here][1]t..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/viBUj.png

Edit; after some work Im getting alot less errors but I still got some 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f88gN.png

Answer (score 1):

You declared all your variables as doubles but you set calc to accept integers.

edit: Also, you're placing the doubles into a local variable declared as a passed parameter in your method definition instead of a simple localized variable. There are quite a few ways you could do things differently, but considering this seems to be a piece of homework or a learning experience I'd say you should remove grade from the definition, change your remaining parameters to doubles, and declare grade within your method body. There are a few more things to do but this should get you down the road.

Comment: ok so after fixing some of the dumb mistakes I did I keep getting a few more error messages http://i.imgur.com/xVale.png

Comment: in your main method on line 18, you used grade without declaring a data type for it. In your calc method you use a local variable (calc) to store the calculation of the variables without declaring it, and then at the end of that method you returned grade instead of calc.

Comment: ok so after fix that I got it narrod down to two errors which are this http://i.imgur.com/c0Kdu.png

Comment: grade = calc(int grade) won't work because you're declaring a variable inside a method call which is expecting five arguments. calc must be called (for example) like this: calc(a, b, c, d, e). So you should do something like: grade = calc(0,cw,hw,qz,fe);

Comment: When you wrote the method you told it to accept 5 arguments when you declared the method to have 5 parameters. Since your method uses the first parameter to store the temporary calculation that it returns (using a local version of grade, which is different than the one declared in the program body) you just need to declare an initial value which might as well be zero since you're going to over-write the initial value in the method body.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your prototype for calc is:

```
int calc(int grade);
```

But your definition is

```
int calc(int grade, int cw, int hw, int qz, int fe) {
```

Update your prototype to match your definition and it should solve that problem.

Comment: With your latest screenshot, http://i.imgur.com/c0Kdu.png, on the line: grade = calc(int grade); you need to pass the 5 variables you collected. I see another problem with this code. 1) you're returning grade, so there's no need to pass grade into calc(); 2) you're sending too few arguments when you call the function. Function prototypes, definitions, and calls must all match.

Comment: Instead of grade = calc(int grade), you just pass the variables, rather than their type identifiers, e.g., calc(grade, cw, hw, qz, fe);